# How to assign the same Id to Anagram of character?

Tags: javascript, anagram

I want to assign the same Id to Anagram chain of character with Javascript.

like :

Paul Leblanc

and

Leblanc Paul

(sorry for my english )

Thank you by advance

Comment: Characters don't have IDs, and elements must not have the same id. Please elaborate your question and show the code you have at hands.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a unique id based on a string with the same result for anagram, you need to sort the letters of you string and make the id based on this.

To get your seed from a string :

```
function getSeed(str) { return str.split('').sort().join('') }
```

you can then generate an id with this seed, by making a md5 for example.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbie !

Can you help me more to for the md5 with my exemple ?

Thanks you :)